# What is the difference between heat lamps and infrared space heaters?

Tags: heating, energy-efficiency, bulb, electric-heat

Maybe these are pretty much the same thing. I'm interested in the difference between heat lamps and infrared space heaters, especially as regards

1. How they are normally used
2. How they should be used
3. How energy-efficient they are under various conditions

Thanks!

Comment: That’s fairly broad so I will focus on lamps , most of your lamps are smaller because since the lamps get hot they require special fixtures so heat lamps for the most part are limited to the fixture design many are 300w per lamp Or smaller. where your heaters are 1150W + and there are 240v and some gas fired infrared heaters that have much higher outputs. So you can see this is quite broad and would more focus to properly answer.

Comment: Thanks! So one big difference is that lamps tend to be for lower-output applications?

Comment: Yes even commercial grade heat lamps are usually 1/2 the output of a IR heater available at a store.

Answer (score 1):

The exact space heater in question would effect answer, generally both use invisible light to heat surfaces rather than heating the air. What varies is how much of the IR is reflected and how much is absorbed by the fixture or lamp then locally projected by the device.

Electrical heat is not very efficient, any watt produces the same heat no matter how dispersed, 3412 btu's per kw/hr.

Comment: Thanks! So the mechanism ("lamp" vs "infrared heater") tends not to affect the efficiency very much, and it's more driven by other features like how the heat is directed?

Comment: re: "_Electrical heat is not very efficient_"; 100%'s efficient as physics allows.